# UWP : Can't retrieve files correctly from LocalFolder

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

During the `OnLaunched` of my application I create a file like this :

```
await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(Keys.AdContentBig);
```

Later on, I write some bytes into that file (the file is an image)

The file is well written, and well present :

[image]

After that I want to retrieve that URI of that file using the `ms-appdata:` schema to show it, what I do is this :

```
var f = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(Keys.AdContentBig);
uriDestination = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/LocalState/" + f.Name, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
imageSource = new BitmapImage(uriDestination );
```

and on XAML, a typical :

```
<Image Source="{x:Bind Vm.imageSource, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The compiler doesn't complain about the existence of the file, nor does it break or something, nothing happens and the image is not shown, surely I'm doing somehing wrong with `"ms-appdata:///local/LocalState/"`, if I am please correct me, or tell me what else I'm missing.

Comment: Try it with only `"ms-appdata:///local/" + f.Name`. Afaik `ms-appdata:///local/my_folder` equals `C:\Data\Users\username\AppData\{guid}\LocalState‌​\my_folder`.

Comment: @sibbl Thx sir, please put that as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it with only `"ms-appdata:///local/" + f.Name`.

`ms-appdata:///local/my_folder`
equals
`C:\Data\Users\username\AppData\{guid}\LocalState‌​\my_folder`